# How to get cell coordinates of active cell from other spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this script for getting coordinates of active cell to UI.

```
function createUI(id, url, title) {  


  var UI = UiApp.createApplication().setHeight(300).setWidth(300).setTitle("Výběr dat pro převod provizí.");

  var HandlerGetCellCoordinatesCisloNavrhu = UI.createServerHandler("getCellCoordinatesCisloNavrhu").addCallbackElement(hiddenID);
  var firstCellCisloNavrhu = UI.createTextBox().setId("first_cell_cislo_navrhu").addFocusHandler(HandlerGetCellCoordinatesCisloNavrhu);
  var panel1 = UI.createAbsolutePanel().add(firstCellCisloNavrhu);
  var captionPanel1 = UI.createCaptionPanel().setText("první buňka s číslem návrhu smluv").add(panel1);


  var button = UI.createButton().setText("submit");
  var vertical = UI.createVerticalPanel()
  .add(captionPanel1)
  .add(button);
  var pole = UI.add(vertical);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(UI);
}

function getCellCoordinatesCisloNavrhu(e){
  var id = "1uVb_ndCQQNu3DCyQQQOwMAAHUcApRnhQn3patIYBZS8";
  var UI = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange();
  var row = cell.getRow();
  var column = cell.getColumn();
  var cellCoordinates = row + "," + column;
  UI.getElementById("first_cell_cislo_navrhu").setText(cellCoordinates);
  return UI;
}
```

It works well but I need get coordinates from other spreadsheet then the script contains. There is the issue. If I open the other spreadsheet by "openById" I get only the "1, 1" coordinates, though I have physically opened the other spreadsheet and set active cell to other position. I know it is clear that there is set A1 cell as active by opening sheet, but I don't konw how to evade it.

Has someone any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to include a script in the spreadsheets that runs with a time trigger (no on click is available alas), store the coordinates in a hidden tab. Retrieve the coordinates with importrange function.